# Send email to any receiver django

Tags: python, django, email

I used data from class Create_order  and I would like to send email to the customer . He write his email address and get the message with his Name and Surname .

views.py

```
class Create_order (CreateView):
        template_name ='games/create.html'
        model= Order
        fields = ['person_name','person_surname','street','city','email_order']

        def post(self, request, pk):
            form = self.get_form()
            if form.is_valid():
                order = form.save()
                order.game_id = int(pk)
                order.save()
                send_mail(
                    'Zamówienie {}'.format(order.pk),
                    'Witaj {}'.format (order.person_name,order.person_surname),
                    'luke.rudzinski@gmail.com',
                   ['email_order'],


                    )
```

settings.py

```
 ALLOWED_HOSTS = []
    EMAIL_HOST ='smtp.gmail.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_USER ='luke.rudzinski@gmail.com'
    EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = '*****'
    EMAIL_PORT = 587
    EMAIL_USE_TLS = True
```

I my form can't send email to any receiver
[Image with error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SLTXp.jpg)

Comment: Please copy and past the error instead of a screenshot.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to send an email to the string `'email_order'` which is incorrect.

Perhaps you mean:

```
send_mail(
    'Zamówienie {}'.format(order.pk),
    # Note you need a second {} for the surname
    'Witaj {} {}'.format (order.person_name,order.person_surname),
    'luke.rudzinski@gmail.com',
    [order.email_order],
)
```

Comment: Thank you for your help it works , but I don't know why surname wasn't printed on message